Refresh JWT Tokens using PyJWT
Upon using a login system bases on authentication tokens stored in cookies, I am encountering issues while trying to refresh the token without using login and password again. Is it possible to refresh the jwt tokens using PyJWT ?
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('userJwt')
        if token is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated!')
        response = Response(status=200)
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            # payload['exp'] = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=20)
            # new_token = jwt.encode(payload, "secret", algorithm="HS256")
            # response.set_cookie(key='userJwt', value=new_token, httponly=True)
            return Response({"message": "Expired"}, status=200)
        user = User.objects.filter(id=payload['id']).first()
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        response.data = serializer.data
        return response

